# How to send a mailer on update of an object in a HABTM join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, actionmailer

I have a User object and an Orgs object that are associated through a HABTM join table. I want to send an email to the users when the Orgs object is updated AND the Org.approved value is set to true. I have an approved boolean on the Org.

I think I've gotten most of the way there but I need help with the step of actually sending the email.

Here's my code

```
class OrgMailer < ApplicationMailer

  default from: 'myemail@example.co'

  def org_approved(user, org)
    @user = user
    @orgs = User.orgs.all
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Your listing has been approved.')
  end
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

 has_and_belongs_to_many :orgs, join_table: :orgs_users
end
```

Org.rb

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, join_table: :orgs_users
  # after_update :send_approved_listing_email, only: [:update]

  attachment :company_image


  def send_approved_listing_email
       OrgMailer.org_approved(i).deliver_now if org.approved === true
  end


end
```

**UPDATED: ADDED ORG_CONTROLLER**

I've edited my code to look like the answer below but am now getting a new error: uninitialized constant Org::OrgsUser

It's caused when I hit the @org.users << @user line in the create action.

If I delete this line, I'm able to create an org but it's not associating properly.

org_controller.rb

```
class OrgsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_org, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  def index
    @orgs = Org.all
    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @org = Org.new
  end

  def contest
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @org = Org.new(org_params)
    @org.users << @user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @org.save
        format.html { redirect_to thankyou_path, notice: 'Your listing was successfully created. Our team will approve your listing after review.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @org }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @org.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @org.update(org_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @org, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @org }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @org.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @org.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orgs_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def tagged
  if params[:tag].present?
    @orgs = Org.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @orgs = Org.postall
  end
end

  private
    def set_org
      @org = Org.find(params[:id])
    end

    def org_params
      params.require(:org).permit(:twitter, :linkedin, :facebook, :name, :offer, :offercode, :url, :descrption, :category, :approved, :company_image, :tag_list => [])
    end
end
```

I'm using active admin for my admin panel and have a batch action to update any selected orgs and approve them. I think what I'm missing is that in the send_approved_listing_email method I need to iterate through the orgs and email each user when the org is approved.

Right now nothing happens on update so I'm sure I'm not doing this correctly. What am I missing? How should I write this?

Comment: You may have an argument error in `send_approved_listing_email`. `OrgMailer.org_approved` is expecting `(user, org)` but it's only getting `i` which looks like it's undefined anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a model for the join table rather than using habtm. That way you can use a callback when the join object is saved:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orgs_users
  has_many :orgs, through: :orgs_users
end

class Org < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orgs_users
  has_many :users, through: :orgs_users

end

class OrgsUsers < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :org
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :send_approved_listing_email
  def send_approved_listing_email
    OrgMailer.org_approved(user, org).deliver_now if org.approved === true
  end
end
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. I'll try this out. Do I just have a user_id and org_id in the OrgsUsers table?

Comment: Yes that's all you need at minimum. You could also keep additional data in that model if you like, such as the result of the email delivery.

Comment: I updated my question as I'm getting a new error. I need a little help debugging the org controller and then I think it should work.

Comment: What happens if you call `org.users` on an existing Org record that you know has users?

Comment: I reset my db but wehn I call Org.first.users I get the same error message that I get when I run create.

Comment: Did you make a new model file for `orgs_user.rb` under `app/models`?